# Filling Between Curves

Tags: plotting, filling

I want to fill in the region between the curves.

So far I have this:

```
Plot[{x + 7, 9 - x^2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: So what's the logic here? 1) Fill to the left of the point of intersection? 2) Fill when curve 2 is above curve 1? 3) Fill the first enclosure between the two curves?

Comment: @rm-rf I closed this question because as it has been interpreted it is a duplicate, and I wish to respect the older, original question from a contributing member.  However, that makes the answers here somewhat harder to find.  Do you think this might be a case where a merge is appropriate?  I believe the original can be modified so that all the answers make sense.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Why does it make this harder to find? Duplicates show up exactly as any other post and are just as searchable/rep-earnable. It's only the "answerless duplicates" that are automatically redirected. But I agree that a merge might not be all that bad (esp. since only belisarius has an answer there), and Anon has an apparently general version of a shading function...

Comment: @rm-rf I meant somewhat harder to find than if the close went the other way.  Since you agree this is a good candidate for a merge, e.g. there is no Accepted answer here, I shall do that tomorrow unless you do it first.

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you can use the +/- option of `Filling`

```
Plot[{x + 7, 9 - x^2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, White}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I would use `None` not `White`.

Comment: @rcollyer While I'm changing the colors, do you know off hand what the default blue is?

Comment: @bobthechemist See my answer.

Comment: @ybeltukov my web browser wasn't refreshing fast enough...

Comment: The simplest way to get that color is to run, `ColorData[1][1]`.  Then fiddle with the `Opacity` until you're content.

Comment: @bobthechemist Your answer was a few seconds before. I was late while extracting the default color from `Plot[...]//InputForm` :)

Comment: No need to extract any color... just use `Automatic` :)

Comment: @rm-rf Oh, right!

Comment: @rm-rf true, but when you don't have `Automatic` behavior, you sometimes need to get the info anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It's like rm-rf says in his comments, it's not really clear what the logic is. There are already plenty of ways to use `Filling` to produce the requested plot but here's a more general function to facilitate arbitrary logic:

```
shadeBoundedArea[plot_, region_] := Module[{rangex, rangey},
  {rangex, rangey} = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[plot];
  Show[
   plot,
   RegionPlot[region, Evaluate@{x, Sequence @@ rangex}, 
    Evaluate@{y, Sequence @@ rangey}]
   ]
  ]

Clear[x, y];

p = Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1.5}]

shadeBoundedArea[p, f1[x] < y < f2[x]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since `Filling` shades between two curves in the plot, add an extra curve that serves as the limit.

```
Plot[{Max[x + 7, 9 - x^2], x + 7, 9 - x^2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[{x + 7, 9 - x^2}, {x, 0, 1.5}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {{Opacity[0.2], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}, None}}}]
```

[image]

Update: you can use `Automatic` instead of `{Opacity[0.2], Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]}`.