# Shading a region where an inequality is satisfied

Tags: plotting, bugs, regions, inequalities, filling

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I'm creating solution sets for a calculus course and need to shade the region in $\mathbb R^2$ such that $x^2 < y < x^4$. This is what I have so far:

```
Plot[{x^2,x^4}, {x, -2, 2},PlotRange->{-1,5},PlotStyle->{Automatic,Red},
     Filling->{1->{{2},{LightBlue,White}}}]
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following picture. In particular, the region in the interval $(-1,0)$ is shaded. How can I avoid this?[image: this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filling Between Curves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33126/filling-between-curves)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate but it isn't. The issue here is that the OP is using the correct syntax, but the filling is nevertheless incorrect (possibly caused by the curves touching at 0 but not crossing). Looks like a bug to me. I guess a workaround may be to lower the x^2 function a tiny bit.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior in V9.0.1 and V10.2

Comment: Same bug in Version 8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I stated in my comment below the post, the filling syntax used by the OP is correct. The behavior seen in the plot is a bug.

A workaround is to simply increase the number of plot points. The following works:

```
Plot[{x^2, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, White}}}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update

Actually, it is not a *small* plot point number that seems to be the cause. Depending on the `PlotPoint` setting two of the four areas are either incorrectly filled or incorrectly not filled. The following plot shows the filling of those areas as a function of the `PlotPoint` value (1 is filled, 0 is not filled):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Aha, nice catch +1.

Comment: There will be an update. There's more to it.

Comment: You beat me to your update: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O6ojv.gif.  There's an interesting "discontinuity" at 49 and 53 plot points. The `x^2` curve jumps to the `x^4` for a point or two at `x == 1`.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I noted that as well. Do you agree that we can tag this question with the "bugs" tag? Also, can I use your animation as an additional illustration?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Since Filling shades between two curves in the plot, add an extra curve that serves as the limit.

How about

```
Plot[{Max[x^2, x^4], x^2, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
```

[image]

To remember

```
Plot[{Min[x^2, x^4], x^2, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Aha! A clever trick indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got this [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33126/filling-between-curves)

```
Plot[{Max[x^2, x^4], x^2, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, 
PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Comment: just saw the answer by @Lou which I believe is from the same source.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `Region*` functionality:**

The advantages of this approach are that one does not need to include additional curves to fill in the desired region and the description of the region is mathematical. The downside is that using `Region` commands may be accompanied with their own challenges.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 < y < x^4, {{x, -2, 2}, {y, -1, 5}}];

p1 = Plot[{x^2, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}
   , PlotRange -> {-1, 5}
   , PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}
   ];

p2 = RegionPlot[reg
   , PlotStyle -> HatchFilling[]
   , BoundaryStyle -> None
   ];

gr = Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}
     , ImageSize -> Small
     ] & /@ {Red, ColorData[97][1], HatchFilling[]};

legend = SwatchLegend[{Red, ColorData[97][1], None}
   , {x^4, x^2, x^2 < y < x^4}
   , LegendMarkers -> gr
   , LegendMarkerSize -> 20];

Legended[
 Show[p1, p2]
 , Placed[legend, {0.65, 0.8}]
 ]
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Another way is decreasing the `MaxRecursion` to `<=1`.
  We compare with the four cases.( Version 14.0 )

```
plots = Plot[{x^2, x^4}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, White}}}, MaxRecursion -> #, 
     PlotLabel -> "MaxRecursion=" <> ToString@#] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 4};
GraphicsGrid[Partition[plots, 2, 2]]
```

[image]

- I belive that one of the problem is that `y=x^2` and `y=x^4` tangent at `x=0` so `x^2-x^4` does not change the sign at `x=0`.