# How do I shade in the region between two plots?

Tags: graphics

I would like to plot two functions and shade in the area between them to illustrate an integration example.

I have this into mathematica:

```
Plot[{4 - x^2, 8 - 2 x^2}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

with this result:

[image]

I tried using the drawing tools to no avail.
Is there a simple way to shade in the contained region between the two plots?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Plot[{4 - x^2, 8 - 2 x^2}, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
Plot[{4 - x^2, 8 - 2 x^2}, {x, -2, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Reference:**

[Filling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

**Relative:**

[Filling between curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33126/filling-between-curves)

**Credits:**

*@eldo

@Jason B*